# How to substitute words in git rebase file

Tags: vim, git, vimrc

I'm trying to set up visual mode mappings for quickly editing git's generated rebase list from when doing interactive rebase (e.g. `git rebase --interactive upstream/master`). In such you're presented with a text file that looks like this:

```
pick 12345678 commit message 1
pick 23456789 commit message 2
pick 34567890 commit message 3
```

What I'd like to do is to do `<c-v>` and select the lines I'd like to switch over to another rebase method, e.g. use `<localleader>f` to change from `pick` to `fixup` in the first word of the line. I'd like to make this a bit fault tolerant, so it doesn't do this for other lines, like comments and empty lines.

What I've tried doing is to do a `:substitute` with a regexp group to only pick up on valid words: `(pick|reword|edit|squash|fixup|exec|drop)`. Here is what I currently have in `.vimrc`.

```
autocmd FileType gitrebase vnoremap <buffer> <localleader>p :s/^\(pick\|reword\|edit\|squash\|fixup\|exec\|drop\)/pick/<cr>
autocmd FileType gitrebase vnoremap <buffer> <localleader>r :s/^\(pick\|reword\|edit\|squash\|fixup\|exec\|drop\)/reword/<cr>
autocmd FileType gitrebase vnoremap <buffer> <localleader>e :s/^\(pick\|reword\|edit\|squash\|fixup\|exec\|drop\)/edit/<cr>
autocmd FileType gitrebase vnoremap <buffer> <localleader>s :s/^\(pick\|reword\|edit\|squash\|fixup\|exec\|drop\)/squash/<cr>
autocmd FileType gitrebase vnoremap <buffer> <localleader>f :s/^\(pick\|reword\|edit\|squash\|fixup\|exec\|drop\)/fixup/<cr>
autocmd FileType gitrebase vnoremap <buffer> <localleader>x :s/^\(pick\|reword\|edit\|squash\|fixup\|exec\|drop\)/exec/<cr>
autocmd FileType gitrebase vnoremap <buffer> <localleader>d :s/^\(pick\|reword\|edit\|squash\|fixup\|exec\|drop\)/drop/<cr>
```

Unfortunately the regexes don't match anything. I tried adding a `\=` at the end of the pattern to match 0 or 1 of any word in the group and it adds the replacement before the word it is supposed to substitute.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're re-inventing [fugitive](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive).

Comment: Does the match work in interactive mode? Magic setting?

Comment: @SatoKatsura I'm not sure what you mean. Does fugitive handle gitrebase? A cursory look on the README tells me nothing of this.

Comment: @Philippos I tried doing it manually in gitrebase file like this `:s/^\(pick\|reword\)/fixup/` and that works. The mapping does not however and I get a `Pattern not found` error.

Comment: @Spoike IIRC this exact use is shown in one of Drew Neil's screencasts.

Comment: Or perhaps it was [gitv](https://github.com/gregsexton/gitv) rather than `fugitive`.

Comment: @SatoKatsura link or it didn't happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an escaping thing. Either always use `\\|` instead of `\|` or try

```
autocmd FileType gitrebase vnoremap <buffer> <localleader>p :s/\v^(pick\|reword\|edit\|squash\|fixup\|exec\|drop)/pick/<cr>
```

Comment: The `|` is special in command-line mode to combine multiple commands in one line, so you have to escape it. So your backslash is eaten as escape by the command-line and is missing in your `sed`